# Is is possible to override a suggest.js function in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Wordpress uses suggest.js to help autocomplete queries, which I am using.

However, as my php lookup returns an array I do not want the field to show as the json_encoded data. From what I can tell there is no simple way in suggest.js to intercept the **displayItems** javascript function so that it will first parse the returned data and only display certain fields.

The function in my scripts.js is as follows :

```
    $("#producturl").suggest(ajaxurl + "?action=fetch_ajax_products_list" ,
    {
        delay: 50, minchars: 1,onSelect: function()
        {
            do_something(this.value);
        }
    });
```

**fetch_ajax_products_list** is the php function that returns a json_encoded array with three elements (id,title and guid), which is correctly passed on as **this.value**. I only want the title displayed, but when selected the field will be updated to show the guid. Complicating things is the title can be duplicated, so creating new sql queries based on a selection is not possible without the id field.

I don't see any methods of changing the way the data returned by suggest is displayed, so I am guessing it needs to be over-ridden.

Google does not return much help for suggest.js.

I hope that makes sense, and any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I have just changed my code not to json_encode the data, rather using commas as separators, and then splitting the result. At least the fields looks neater in the suggest drop-down list. So I added it as a comment as it's not an answer, just a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to modify `wp-inludes/js/jquery/suggest.js` to accept option `filter`.

```
options.filter = options.filter || function(txt) {
    return txt;
}
```

Then pass response through filter.

```
items = parseTxt(options.filter(txt), q);
```

Setup

```
$("#producturl").suggest(ajaxurl + "?action=fetch_ajax_products_list" ,
{
    delay: 50,
    minchars: 1,
    filter: function(response) {
        // JSON.parse, etc.
    },
    onSelect: function() {
        do_something(this.value);
    }
});
```

Whole modified script [here](https://gist.github.com/ruslanas/3503b103d3b278126e84). Lines modified [297-299](https://gist.github.com/ruslanas/3503b103d3b278126e84#file-suggest-js-L297-L299) and [125](https://gist.github.com/ruslanas/3503b103d3b278126e84#file-suggest-js-L125).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it looks very promising. I'll give it a try and report back shortly. I was thinking not to edit suggest.js though, as upgrading wordpress might overwrite it at some point. I think it would be a better idea to have any code in a separate js file if it's possible. I would guess duplicate the file in the plugin folder and then enque that file rather than the original.

Comment: Yes this did the job perfectly thank you. I created my own "mysuggest.js" and enqued it. Sorry for the late reply.... just been a bit caught up.